# Cordova/Gradle Uses com.android.support:support alpha instead of stable

Tags: android, cordova, gradle, android-support-library

I am having a problem this week trying to build my project with Cordova for some reason when i build:

```
cordova build android
```

gradle fetches com.android.support:support alpha instead of com.android.support:support-v4 which is the base for my android project minSdkVersion 16. (com.android.support:support-v4 supports minSdkVersion 14).

But when i force com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.0 into my build.gradle file it works:

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.0'
    }
}
```

Why does it pick alpha which is unstable? I didn't have this problem before, also i did a clean clone of my master branch which i didn't change in a long time and it didn't have any problem i experience the same issue.

Also i tried:

- Clearing gradle cache
- Removing all my tools/clis
- Removing android studio and using sdk command line tools instead

**UPDATE:**

Revision 28.0.0 Alpha 1

Release date: 08/03/2018

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that by default the support library being used is -

```
com.android.support:support-v4:+
```

The + sign pulls the latest Android support library which is `28.0.0 Alpha 1` Therefore your way of forcing the gradle to use 27.1.0 is the right way to go about building your APK